# gui die during emit on pyqt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

why gui die when i us function work(), i want to show some word on gui without block gui, so decide to use qthread do this job. when i debug the program ,when the program run to "self._signal.emit(msg)",the gui will die.

```
q1=Queue.Queue()

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)      
        self.display1=textbrowser1display()
        self.display1._signal.connect(self.display11)
        self.display1.start()



class textbrowser1display(QThread):
    _signal=pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(textbrowser1display, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print "screen1 emit working"
        time.sleep(0.1)
        while global_list.display:
            if not global_list.q1.empty():
                msg=str(global_list.q1.get(block=True))
                self._signal.emit(msg)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
class job():
    def work(self):
        global_list.q1.put("initbus",block=True)
```

Comment: what are `self.display11`, `global_list`, etc?, provide a [MCVE]

Comment: typo: change `_signal=pyqtSignal()` to `_signal=pyqtSignal(str)`, 
When you create the signal you must indicate the type of data it will send, in your case `str`

Comment: i test when i try to get some message on q1(queue), the process will block. i use another way to write this function, it work.maybe i have not understand completely with queue operation.